# Responsive SVG / Data Images

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I've converted two SVG images to css/data images, first time working this way.

I want the images to be responsive, in the centre and with a max-width of 800px.

I have made the height 100% and width 100% but when the browser is narrow, there is a huge gap underneath the images which makes the user have to scroll a long way to get to the next image, I want it right up against it.

I've messed about with this all day and can't figure it out.

I have attached a fiddle to see what I have so far and please see below the css code.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="front"></div>
  <div class="front"></div>
</div>
```

and here's the css minus the front style as it would not post correctly.

```
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background:pink;
}
.container {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

Here's the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/gjkx1ye5/1/

Comment: Just to be clear, the idea is that for a situation like this: http://i.imgur.com/FRyfA6D.png the pink area below the orange box should not be visible but rather covered up by the following orange box butting up against the first one?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, works ok on a wider browser but as soon as I narrow the browser, I get a huge gap

Comment: If you just need the background-images to be next to one another (and not, say, child text), just change `background-repeat` to a value of `repeat-y`, no? If you do need more than the background-images next to each other, I think you'll have to use JavaScript.